# Automating Database Deployment with TeamCity

Tags: database, automation, teamcity

We are currently using TeamCity and I am wondering if it is possible to have it handle our database process. Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. User runs a build
2. TeamCity remotes into database server (or tells a program to via command line)
3. SQL script is run that updates record(s)
4. Copys the mdf/ldf back to team city for manipulation in the build

Alternatively it could work like this if this is easier

1. User logs in to database server and runs batch file which does the following:
2. SQL script is run that updates record(s)
3. MDF/LDF is copied and then uploaded to repository
4. Build process is called through web hook with parameter

I cant seem to find anything that even gets me started. Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you are trying to make a copy of a central (development?) database, with a few modification being made to it?

Answer (score 0):

From your description above I am going to guess you are trying to make a copy of a shared (development) database, which you then want to modify and run tests against on the CI server.

There is nothing to stop you doing what you describe with TeamCity (as it can run any arbitrary code as a build step) but it is obviously a bit clunky and it provides no specific support for what you are trying to do.

Some alternative approaches:

- Consider connecting directly to your shared database, but place all your operations within a transaction so you can discard all changes. If your database offers the capability, consider database snapshots.
- Deploy a completely new database on the CI when you need one. Automate the schema deployment and populate it will test data. Use a lightweight database such as SQL Local DB, or SQL Lite.